# How to make a function argument do something before and after being passed in one-liner in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to make an object do something before and after being passed as an argument into a function, but (1) without modifying the function and (2) in a neat way.

Here is the first one that comes to my mind, with RAII.
However, I think the expression `(x.lock(), x)` is ugly.

I think there would definitely be a good solution, but I can't think of one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// I can change this class
struct RAII {
  RAII() {
    cout << "do sth globally" << endl;
  }
  ~RAII() {
    cout << "revert it" << endl;
  }
};

class A {
  public:
    // I can change this function, too.
    auto lock() {
      return RAII();
    }
};

void f(const A& obj) {
  cout << "a function that I can't change" << endl;
}

int main() {
  A x;
 // I think the expression is somewhat ugly.
 // Can I make this a more neat one-liner, like f(x.locked())?
  f((x.lock(), x));
}
```

The output is the same as below.

```
do sth globally
a function that I can't change
revert it
```

Comment: Does it need to be a one-liner? Usually it just makes the code more confusing

Comment: How about wrapping the function?

Comment: You have code that works and does what you want but you want to beautify it? That's usually very opinion-based.

Comment: You could wrap it in an object. Like `function(Log(a));`

Comment: Okay, I can just make the function wrapped. Sorry for a silly question.

Comment: @wk_j Would [this](https://godbolt.org/z/55eGzfT4q) be something you could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it when the function and call are:

```
void f(const A& obj);
f(x);
```

and you are not allowed to change these. There is no way to make the object aware of a reference being taken.

You can however, call a different function:

```
void f2(const A& obj) {
     obj.before();
     f(obj);
     obj.after();
}

f2(x); // <- one line
```

With RAII that would be something along the line of

```
struct helper {
      const A& obj;
      helper(const A& obj) : obj(obj) { before(obj); }
      ~helper() { after(obj); }
};

void f2(const A& a) {
    helper h{a};
    f(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the function doesn't work for you?

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    void preProc() const {
        std::cout<<"Pre-proc\n";
    }
    void postProc() const {
        std::cout<<"Post-proc\n";
    }
};

struct RAII {
  explicit RAII(const A& a): a_(a){
    a_.preProc();
  }
  ~RAII() {
    a_.postProc();
  }
  private:
  const A& a_;
};

void f(const A& a){

}

void fWrap(const A& a){
    RAII r(a);
    f(a);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    fWrap(a);
}
```

Obviously this is just more convenience over just writing `a.preProc()` and `a.postProc()` every time before the function call. If it's just a single instance, the entire `RAII` class can just be removed!

Edit:

My motivation for RAII was perhaps a bit myopic. As @largest_prime_is_463035818 rightly adds, if `f()` actually threw an exception, the `~RAII()` would be called, allowing cleanup of anything that had been set up in the `a.preProc()` which isn't available in the vanilla function-wrap scenario.

Comment: raii is not just about convenience, when `f` throws an exception the destructor of `r` is called, but a call to `a.postProc` would not